# Does the term "walkable roof" exist in English?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology

I'm writing a paper about flat roofs. I wanted to use the term "walkable roof" to describe a roof that can be used on a daily basis (e.g. a roof terrace), but I'm not sure if this term exists in English language? What name would you suggest for this type of a roof?

[image]

Comment: Google "walk-on": maybe that fits the bill.

Comment: It's perfectly valid terminology, though it likely does not carry the specific connotation you seek.

Comment: There's the [*widow's walk,*](https://www.google.com/search?q=widow%27s+walk&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ3ZPTyeHLAhXH9h4KHezODdIQsAQILQ#mhpiv=2) but that's just a smallish platform on top of a peaked roof.

Comment: I think the technical term is either a *deck roof*, or a *roof deck*. One of them is a roof which simply covers an outdoor deking area. The other may be a roof which is 'walkable'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Maybe the photo will help. This is the "walkable" roof I was referring to (opposed to a "not walkable'' roof that is covered with gravel).

Comment: Perhaps the term *walkable roof* does exist. If you Google it, all kinds of examples come up.

Comment: The thing is, there are so many possible configurations of such a roof, and so many different cultures (note that different cities will develop different styles), that there is not any really consistent terminology.  A term that may be fine to describe the roof for a novel or story will likely be insufficient to describe it for legal or architectural purposes.

Comment: I'm aware of that and since I'm not a native English speaker I was hoping that someone who is can tell me is it correct to use this word (or if not, which word is a better choice). In an architectural sense. I guess I will go with it and hope for the best :)

Comment: Why is a roof covered with gravel not walkable (assuming shoes)?  Although I've never heard the term walkable roof, I inferred that it was a flat roof or one with a very shallow pitch.

Comment: @ab2 Roof covered with gravel can also be walked on, but only during maintenance or repair works, it is not meant to be used each day.

Comment: @ab2 You NEED TO BE AWARE AS A MATTER OF SAFETY that the fact that a roof is covered with gravel does not necessarily mean it is safe to walk on. A lot of flat roofs are covered with asphalt. The gravel is often there simply to protect the asphalt from weathering. The inherent problem with flat roofs is that rain water does not drain. So they are designed to hold moisture until it is dried off. The gravel plays some part in this, which, not being an architect, or building surveyor, I do not fully understand.

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for the warning!  I'm not going to walk on any roofs that don't have tables, chairs, umbrellas, trees and plants in pots and people who will bring me a drink.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

As a former building contractor (and native speaker of North American English) I would say that the term "walkable roof" does exist, but does not have the meaning that you want.

"Walkable roof", particularly in trade jargon would mean "a roof that is not too steep to walk on"; ie. slope is less than 8 inches rise (or so) over each horizontal foot. More likely to be used in reference to a roof with some slope than a totally flat one.

eg. "The roofers are replacing our roof; as it is not walkable, they are building scaffolding all around our house!"

I would call the type of roof shown in the photo a "rooftop patio".

Comment: Good answer. Another term that I see multiple times in Google Books search results is "paved roof" (or "paved roof deck" or "paved roof terrace").

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understood correctly - In English there is not one word that can describe paved type of a roof and one that is describing roof covered with gravel (or something else, but not paved)? Two opposite terms for describing two types of flat roofs.

Comment: @Jessie - A "walkable" roof isn't even guaranteed to be flat -- just no so steep that one can't readily walk on it.

Comment: @Jessie - In North America anyways, types of flat roof are normally named by the type of material making up the watertight layer -- so you could have for example a "tar & gravel", EPDM (synthetic rubber) or "torch-on" (a rolled asphalt product) roof. Any of these types can be finished with concrete pavers or other surfaces to make them more friendly to human traffic, but one wouldn't normally name the roof according to this factor. It's kind of an ancilliary feature to the roof itself. "Paved roof" as Sven suggests would make sense, or maybe "livable space"? Concrete roof deck?